# the tokenGetter method does not wait for the promise to be completed before attempting to process the token

Tags: jwt, angular-promise, refresh-token

I am using Jwt tokens for authentication and using a interceptor for adding access token to the requests.I have a `getToken()` method which is checking for token's validity and calling the service for getting new set of tokens. The method is returning promise but the requests are taking the promise before it gets completed and failing to get the updated token.

Below is my code:

```
export class TokenService {

refresh = false;

constructor(public injector: Injector) {
}

public getToken(): string | Promise<string> {
    const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');

    if (!token || !refreshToken) {
        return null;
    }

    if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(refreshToken)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            let tokenPromise;
            if (!this.refresh) {
                this.refresh = true;
                tokenPromise = this.promiseFromObservable(this.getTokenService(localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')));
            }
            return tokenPromise;
        }
    } else {
        return token;
    }
}

getTokenService(refreshToken: string) {
    let http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + refreshToken
        })
    };
    return http.post<Tokens>(location.origin + '/LiveTime/services/v1/auth/tokens?locale=en', null, httpOptions);
}

promiseFromObservable(o): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => o.subscribe((token: Tokens) => resolve(token.token),reject(), err => { console.log(err); return null; }))
        .then((token: Tokens) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', token.token);
            localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', token.refreshToken);
            this.refresh = false;
            return token.token;
        },
            err => { console.log(err); return null; }
        )
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error);reject();
        });
}

}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Please provide us with the error message or the exact problem you are facing

Comment: I am using interceptor for adding access token to the header of all the http requests.Interceptor is calling getToken method to get access token.
But when the access token is getting expired, it is calling another service for renewing the token(Token service) and as it is also a http request, interceptor is calling getToken method again and it is becoming a loop.
So if one request is already called getToken method , other request should wait for the execution of this method (wait for the promise to finish getting the new tokens) and get the updated tokens instead of calling the service again

Comment: @SHIVAMGUPTA Did you manage to solve this issue? As far as I see, auth0-spa-js doesn't have good support for returning a Promise from tokenGetter.